# How to access mongodb spawned by meteor app on a remote server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a meteor application with mongodb running on one of my systems. I want another application running on a different system to be able to access the mongodb that is spawned by my meteor application.

How can I accomplish this because by default the mongodb bind ip is localhost, so it's not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but you can disable the restriction of MongoDB that can be accessed only via localhost.
See: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :( When meteor runs it spawns its own instance of mongodb overriding the configuration file. Does anyone know which file has the settings for spawning the meteor mongodb?

Comment: I use Meteor with MongoDB which is on other SaaS(compose.io) and Meteor can successfully connect to it by setting like `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp`

So it isn't necessarily true that Meteor always spawns its own instance of MongoDB. We can change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is on the **same server**, then use the localhost address:

Meteor tends to expose the MongoDB at its address +1 
(If Meteor is on port 3000, MongoDB is on port 3001).
So your service can access it at `localhost:3001`

If you want to access from **another server**, you need to change the MongoDB config to expose the port to the outside (and probably also set up some firewall rules to only give access to your other server, etc...)

And then use the suggestions above 
`MONGO_URL=mongodb://hostname:port`

Ideally, deploy your MongoDB securely somewhere and plug Meteor and any other app needing it via the connection string.